# Android: passing information from an array to a textview

Tags: java, android, arrays, message-passing

I have set myself up an array with questions and answers as follows:

```
static String[][] question= new String[20][5];

{
    question[0][0] = "what is my name?";
    question[0][1] = "Mark";
    question[0][2] = "Steven";
    question[0][3] = "Alan";
    question[0][4] = "Bob";

    question[1][0] = "what is my age?";
    question[1][1] = "30";
    question[1][2] = "31";
    question[1][3] = "32";
    question[1][4] = "33";
}
```

first square brackets indicates the question number and the second number gives the answer number, all correct answers are in 4th answer.my intention is to build a general app of questions that randomize and to pass to the next screen. I have used this code to generate a random number for the question number. so for e.g. 1st attempt Q5 will come up, attempt 2 Q3 could come up, attempt 3 Q1 could come up etc.

This next block of code is used by the android:onClick="goToQuestions"

```
public void goToQuestions (View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Questions.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

using the above code will successfully move from current activity to questions activity. If i use this code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        int randomArray = (int) (Math.random() *4);
            textView1.setText(question[randomArray][0]);
        }
    });
}
```

it will allow me to generate a random number from the array of questions and print it to my text view when it is in the same activity. I have tried this code below to try to pass the information to the questions screen from the home screen:

```
public void goToQuestions (View v1)
{
    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int randomArray = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    textView1.setText(Questions.question[randomArray][0]);

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, QuizActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have assumed calling android:onClick eliminated the need for an onclick listener. Can anyone provide assistance for how I could finish this correctly. With that last piece of code the app just crashes as I hit the button.

Comment: can you tell me what variable's value you want to save and pass it to the next activity? from which activity to which? elaborate a little. Thanks

Comment: Are you just wanting to pass the question String from your array to the next Activity? If so you can just pass that with your intent and retrieve it once the new Activity launches. Let me know if that's what you're doing and I can show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is not ideal. Create a class that represents a question, and is Parcelable, so you can pass that to your next activity. Something like this

```
public class Question implements Parcelable {
    private final String mQuestion;
    private final List<String> mAnswers;
    private final int mCorrectAnswer;

    public Question(final String question, final List<String> answers, int correctAnswer) {
        mQuestion = question;
        mAnswers = answers;
        mCorrectAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    // implement parcelable interface below
}
```

Then you would receive this on your next activity, deserialize it and show the data as you see fit.

Consider also using fragments instead of activities.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue, firstly thank you all for your assistance. Secondly I was able to do this task using the code I was using, I was just putting it into the wrong class files. I was able to move this code:

```
final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
int randomArray = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
textView1.setText(Questions.question[randomArray][0]);
```

into my onCreate method and it worked fine.